# Protect public API from unwanted "submissions"

Tags: javascript, api, widget, web-component

I've been fiddling around with this issue for quiet some time but couldn't come up with a satisfying solution so far.

We are currently in the process of creating a new public API, which will be used by widgets to get information but also to post back information to the system (like a contact form). As the widgets will be implementend as web components and can be implemented on any page, we don't have control over how the widgets are delivered.

The issue I'm facing now is: how can we protect the API from unwanted submissions (apart from general form validation) so that we can be quiet sure that it's either a submission from that form or that it's a legit POST to the API?

My concerns are, that everything in this case is spoofable (e.g. fetching a form token and submitting it as a header, validating origin headers,...), as it could easily be spoofed i.e. with Postman. I'd be more than happy for any of your experiences and tips into the right direction.

Comment: what about captcha?

Comment: No different from submitting content from any webpage. Only web component related addition could be to create a hash from all of your component code and use that as API access key. If you obfuscate the hash creation part it will deter almost all hackers... unless you are creating a banking API.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try:

- Rate limit based on IP
- Rate limits on general insertions
- Require email validation after send (if you have this data)
- Save sender IP and check with old data, to know if someoe is abusing (a monitoring tip, but maybe is not bad idea)
- Captcha to avoid malicious senders (but not at all)

Have you implemented anything similar? Maybe by seeing what you have, we can see what's missing.

It is also complicated by being public, and allowing access from any system. Perhaps it would be a good idea to evaluate an authentication system, and authenticate from the widget itself, incorporating a rate lim by key.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a public API **without** authentication,
all you can do is make access as hard as possible for hackers.

In other words: put more/complex locks on the door ... *but any lock can be picked*

#### "Lock" code using the URI

The method we used to keep a WebComponent "safe",
was to load the WebComponent from a long URI:

(Modern browsers don't have a 2048 character URI limit any more)

**`https://domain/p1/p2/customeElements/define/secure-api/HTMLElement/p7/p8/webcomponent.js`**

The component code then **decodes** the URI to

```
let p = [domain,p1,p2,"customElements","define","secure-api","HTMLElement",p7,p8]
```

to execute JavaScript:

**`window[p[3]][p[4]](p[5],class extends window[p[6]]{ ...`**

#### More locks

If you throw in some BtoA/AtoB and String.reverse() conversions

`https://domain/AH=V/CV=/==QYvRnY/aW5uZXJ/IVE1M/webcomponent.js`

You have deterred most potential hackers

#### More locks

By generating `webcomponent.js` **server-side** to use the `/domain/` part,
that long URI can be the (unique) handshake between Server and Client

#### More complex locks

Since all state is in the URI, it is easy to apply an address *shifting* mechanism,
every request can be a different URI (makes PostMan unusable and a real pain to debug also :-)

> [and we applied some other trickery I won't explain here]

It won't keep hackers out, but will delay them long enough for the majority to give up.

#### And a mousetrap

In our code/URI encoding we also included a reference to a unique "*mousetrap*" URI.
If we detect 404 activity in that subdir, we know someone is actively picking a lock.
And.. we can interactively lead/direct them to more mousetraps.

We have only had one attempt thus far.

One telephone call (because we know the buyers Domain) was enough to make them stop.

*Hello IT manager of [very-big-well-known] IT company X,

**if** we detect hacking attempts from your company IP address nn.nn.nn.nn,

by law we would have to report this to the authorities*

HTH